# Como concatenar un espacio en un input

Tags: javascript

lo que quiero lograr es que cada 4 digitos, se digite un espacio en un input, de forma automatica, todo lo que encuentro es utilizando JQUERY pero yo utilizo javascript vanila, y no se como poder lograrlo, lo ultimo que intente es lo siguiente:

```
let creditNumber = document.getElementById("numbers")

creditNumber.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    var inputText = event.path[0].value; 
    document.getElementById("numeros").innerHTML = inputText
    console.log(inputText.length)

    if(inputText.length == 4 || inputText.length == 8 || inputText.length == 12) {
        console.log("espacio aca")
     }
})
```

Esto lo que me devuelve es que cada cuarto, octavo y decimo segundo digito que se introduzca en el input, me muestre por consola "Espacio aca", lo que necesito hacer es que se genere un espacio, pero con `inputText = " ";` no me funciona, no se como hacerlo,

Agradezco mucho su ayuda,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si no te quieres meter con regex puedes usar una de las funciones propuestas en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273750/7927192) en el sitio en inglés para dividir la cadena de números en *chunks*.

Luego ya que tengas los chunks, los unes a través de un espacio (pero antes unir cada parte del chunk). Para evitar comportamientos extraños antes tienes que "limpiar" los espacios que has colocado antes.

También puedes usar el atributo [`maxlength`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) del input para limitar la cantidad de caracteres que el usuario puede colocar en el input. En este caso son 19 porque son 4 grupos de 4 -16- más tres espacios que separan esos grupos.

**Edit:** Incluso si te quieres ver elegante puedes agregar una validación para solo permitir números y con esto también mover la parte de la sanitización de los espacios a esta función.

```js
let creditNumber = document.getElementById('numbers');

function chunk(string, n = 4) {
  // Crear un array a partir del string
  // "123" -> ['1', '2', '3']
  const array = Array.from(string);
  const chunks = [];
  // Siempre que haya elementos, separar en grupos de n
  while (array.length > 0) {
    const part = array.splice(0, n)
    chunks.push(part);
  }
  // Unir cada grupo (chunk) y luego unir los grupos por un espacio
  // P.e.: si n = 2:
  // '123' -> ['1', '2', '3'] -> [['1', '2'], ['3']] -> [['12'], ['3']] -> '12 3'
  return chunks.map(chunk => chunk.join('')).join(' ');
}

function validar(string) {
  const numero = string.split(' ').join(''); // Limpiar los espacios
  // Validar que se trate de un número válido:
  // '213s' -> NaN
  // '2135' -> 2135
  if (Number.isNaN(Number(numero))) {
    // Quitar el último elemento (lo que no es número)
    // pero conservar lo que si para evitar que el usuario
    // tenga que escribir todo nuevamente
    return numero.slice(0, -1);
  }
  return numero;
}

creditNumber.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  const value  = validar(this.value);
  this.value = chunk(value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" maxlength="19">
```

Comment: Agradezco infinitamente tu respuesta, no te das una idea la cantidad de cosas que aprendi, voy a tomarme el tiempo de entender parte a parte lo que me escribiste aca. Mil gracias!

Comment: Ricardo, te queria hacer una pregunta, no comprendo bien el funcionamiento de la linea: return chunks.map(chunk => chunk.join('')).join(' '); --- Estuve tocando un poco los valores introducidos ahi, es decir entre las comillas, y se rompe demasiado el codigo, entiendo que el espacio se produce ahi, pero no entiendo la razon

Comment: Básicamente lo que hace `splice` es, a partir del índice **x** eliminar **n** elementos: `array.splice(x, n)`. Al pasarle 0 estamos diciendo que queremos desde el primer elemento y luego que apartir de ese tome los siguientes 4. `splice` modifica el array original por lo que si originalmente habían 8 elementos, a la siguiente vuelta habrán 4 por lo que se repite la secuencia. Ahora el elemento en la posición 4 pasa a ser el 0 y basícamente lo mismo. En esa vuelta al acabarse los elementos, se deja de cumplir la condición del while y se termina el ciclo.

Comment: Si miras el ejemplo de los comentarios en el código entenderás, traté de hacerlo de una forma sencilla. Lo que pasa es que tienes un array de arrays. Esos sub arrays están conformados por los **n** elementos, pero al ser un array primero hay que unirlos con `.join('')`, se coloca así porque los vas a unir con "nada" es decir puedes cambiarlo por una coma pero eso produciría algo como `['1,2,3']`. Al ser "nada", en cambio se produce `['123']`.

Comment: Eso ocurre en `chunk => chunk.join('')`. Con eso obtienes algo como `[['123'], ['456']]` por lo que falta unir esos dos grupos con un espacio, para eso ocupas el segundo `.join(' ')`. Nota el espacio, eso producirá `123 456`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicacion Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué te parece si intentas mi script?

Remplaza tu código con el mio:

```
let creditNumber = document.getElementById('numbers');

creditNumber.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
});
```

Comment: No entiendo para que seria eso

Comment: Sin el afán de ofender o demeritar tu respuesta: ¿Que te parece si en lugar de orillar al compañero a usar tu código -el cual ya dijo que no entiende- mejor le explicas lo que hace para que al menos tenga idea de la solución que le proporcionas? De este modo puedes aportar mejor al OP y a los futuros visitantes.